# How to chain filter with length?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have such a problem, I want to display the number of tweets of each user on his profile, but for some reason I can't.

There is stuck of my code:

Template:

```
<ul v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    <base-card>
      <h3 class="name">
        <router-link :to="`${userPage}${user.id}`">{{
          user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
        }}</router-link>
      </h3>
      <div class="info">
        <p>Followers: {{ followers }}</p>
        <p>
          Tweets:
          {{
            tweets
              .filter((tweet) => tweet.id === user.id)
              .map((tweet) => tweet.tweet)
          }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </base-card>
  </ul>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    users() {
      return this.$store.getters["user/user"];
    },
    followers() {
      return Math.trunc(Math.random() * 100); //dummy function
    },
    tweets() {
      return this.$store.getters["tweets/tweets"];
    },
    userPage() {
      return "/user/";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I know it will be easier to write in Computed,
but in this case, I cannot pass the ID from the template.

Examples of my attempts:

```
tweets
    .filter((tweet) => tweet.id === user.id)
    .map((tweet) => tweet.tweet.length) // In this code, it shows the number of letters in each 
                                           tweet, not the number of tweets.
```

Second attempt:

```
`${tweets
        .filter((tweet) => tweet.id === user.id)
        .map((tweet) => tweet.tweet)}`.length // I do not know what he is showing here, but he does not show correctly.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share sample data for the tweets?

Comment: 0: {id: "Hi9fseEIWmTkGEC45aiTY7E90od2", tweet: "Hello friend", time: "01:05"}

1: {id: "Hi9fseEIWmTkGEC45aiTY7E90od2", tweet: "I'm done", time: "01:18"}

2: {id: "m5TAyyrl7fWm8trnzteCJiKu2vl2", tweet: "I think i'm finishing this project.", time: "04:00"}

3: {id: "w0xmDxJQWnRlkDFnvElu88F4KWg2", tweet: "Hello guys.", time: "04:01"}

4: {id: "w0xmDxJQWnRlkDFnvElu88F4KWg2", tweet: "It's my last project for today..", time: "04:01"}


These tweets come from Firebase real-time database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use Computed Properties, you could create a TweetDetail subcomponent with the ID as a Prop and then create a Computed Getter that uses the Prop's value as its context.

If you want to continue using a single component, you could do this:

In your template, call a new method and pass the user's ID.

```
<span>{{ tweetsCount(userId) }}</span>
```

In your script, add a new method to get the count of tweets with the given ID.

```
// Sample data

tweets = [{user: 1, tweet:'yo'}, {user: 1, tweet:'yo'}, {user: 1, tweet:'yo'}, {user: 2, tweet:'yo'}, {user: 2, tweet:'yo'}];

// Your new method:

tweetsCount(user) {
  return this.tweets.filter((tweet) => tweet.user === user).length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the thought came to my mind that it could somehow be done like this, but for some reason I did not try to do it by calling a function in Metnods. Your solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to create variable `filteredTweets` separately having value of filtered because when using `.map` have no way to access to current state of array.

Here's an example:

```js
const filteredTweets = tweets.filter((tweet) => tweet.id === user.id)

filteredTweets.map((tweet) => {
    console.log(filteredTweets.length) // Number of filtered tweet
    
    console.log(tweet) // Individual tweet
})
```